# how to practically assign repeating objects from groups

Tags: linq, join, grouping

I am having a difficult time finding a proper Linq query to utilize the group output.

I want to populate an existing *students* List where Student class has 2 properties *ID* and and int[] *Repeats* array (can be a list too) to keep how many times they took any of the 4 lectures (L101,L201,L202,L203). So if student takes L101 twice, L202 and L203 once, and but didn't take L201 this should be {2,0,1,1,}

```
class Student{

    public string ID{get;set;}
    public int[] Repeats{get;set;}   //int[0]->L101, int[1]->L201...
}
```

In my main class I do this basic operation for this task:

```
foreach (var student in students)
{
    var countL101 = from s in rawData 
                    where student.Id==s.Id & s.Lecture =="L101" 
                    select;  //do for each lecture

    student.Repeats = new int[4];
    student.Repeats[0] = countL101.Count(); //do for each lecture 
}
```

This works; but I wonder how do you make it practically using Linq in case where there are 100s of lectures?

Comment: Let me know if I made incorrect assumptions about `rawData`, etc and I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using **[Lamba Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx)** rather than query syntax. Then assuming `rawData` is `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` looks something like...

```
class DataRow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Id of Student taking lecture
    /// </summary>
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Lecture { get; set;}
}
```

Then you could do something like...

```
var lectures = rawData.Select(x => x.Lecture).Distinct().ToList();
int i = 0;
lectures.ForEach(l =>
{
    students.ForEach(s =>
        {
            if (s.Repeats == null)
                s.Repeats = new int[lectures.Count];

            s.Repeats[i] = rawData.Count(x => x.Id == s.Id && x.Lecture == l);
        });
    i++;
});
```

Now if `Repeats` could just be of type `IList<int>` instead of `int[]` then...

```
var lectures = rawData.Select(x => x.Lecture).Distinct().ToList();
lectures.ForEach(l =>
{
    students.ForEach(s =>
    {
        if (s.Repeats == null)
            s.Repeats = new List<int>();

        s.Repeats.Add(rawData.Count(x => x.Id == s.Id && x.Lecture == l));
    });
});
```

Things are further simplified if `Repeats` could just be instantiated to a new `List<int>` in the `Student` constructor...

```
class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        Repeats = new List<int>();
    }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public IList<int> Repeats { get; private set; }
}
```

Then you can do it in one line...

```
rawData.Select(x => x.Lecture).Distinct().ToList()
    .ForEach(l =>
    {
        students.ForEach(s =>
        {
            s.Repeats.Add(rawData.Count(x => x.Id == s.Id && x.Lecture == l));
        });
    });
```

Comment: This is what I call a prctical way! Thanks blins, yes the row data has rows Id and Lecture. I tried 3rd option and it works. I wonder though; with the assumption that there are multiple Months of these lectures and each month has a varying incurred cost, mCost in rawData; is it ok if I include SelectMany(x=>x.Lecture, y=>y.Month) in distinction and similar to Repeats, if we choose to populate a s.FailCosts.Add() how do we sum by monthly costs?